# How to crop this paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, pathfinder, crop

I've tested in many ways but I can't crop this paths

I need the white path (selected) crop the letters EP.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all...

Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**

Hold down the <kbd>Option/At</kbd> key

Click-drag across what you *don't* want.

<sub>(This assumes the E and P have been converted to outlines)</sub>